# construct json Object in java and get value from JSONObject

Tags: java, javascript, json

i'm new to JSON

**1.** i got json result in html in following format

JSon Result

```
 Alert(result) 
{"resort0":"Abaco Beach Resort at Boat Harbour","resort1":"Alexandra Resort","room0":"1 Bedroom Luxury Oceanfront Suite","room1":"2 Bedroom Deluxe Ocean View Suite","room2":"Deluxe Garden View Studio","room3":"Deluxe Ocean View Studio","room4":"Deluxe Oceanfront","room5":"Oceanfront","room6":"Superior Oceanfront"}

alert(result.resort1); // alert "undefined"
alert(result.resort0); // alert "undefined"
```

**2**
. how do i get such format with java code JSONObject
is Resorts is key of map ?

```
{
             "Resorts" : [ 
                    { "name"      : "Resort1",  // First element
                      "room1"     : "rooms1"  
                      "room2"     : "rooms2"  },
                    { "name"      : "Resort2",  // Second element
                      "room1"     : "rooms1",
                      "room2"     : "rooms2",  }
                 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful.  If the json to the variable "result" is in your second code block, you can't expect to find any data by using "result.resort0" or "result.resort1".  In your example, result contains a submember called "Resorts" which holds an array of submembers.

In other words, to cycle through all values, I would expect javascript like:

```
for(var i=0; i<result.Resorts.length; i++) {
  alert(result.Resorts[i].name);
  alert(result.Resorts[i].room1);
  alert(result.Resorts[i].room2);
}
```